# Heroku error code H10, not sure what's going on

Tags: django, python-3.x, heroku, error-handling

I'm still a newbie at all this, so I'm not sure what's going on. Been going through the PCC book by Eric Mathes, which is great, but, I've run into some errors here and there even when following the book to a tee due to perhaps using version 1 of the book and not the newest, version 2. Anyhow, I've been trying for days now to figure this h10 error out and I don't understand what's going on here. When I do 'Heroku open', I get an application error and when I investigate, this is what I get:
Thanks in advance!

```
    (11_env) Rezas-MacBook-Pro:learning_log papichulo$ heroku logs --tail
2019-10-04T09:29:06.956667+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2019-10-04T09:41:27.299718+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-10-04T09:41:32.445405+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn learning_log.wsgi --log-file -`
2019-10-04T09:41:35.802943+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2019-10-04T09:41:35.155219+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-04 09:41:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2019-10-04T09:41:35.157841+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-04 09:41:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:11830 (4)
2019-10-04T09:41:35.158031+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-04 09:41:35 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2019-10-04T09:41:35.163938+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-04 09:41:35 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2019-10-04T09:41:35.181361+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-04 09:41:35 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2019-10-04T09:41:36.545969+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2019-10-04T09:41:36.519031+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2019-10-04T09:41:36.252946+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-04 09:41:36 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-10-04T09:41:36.252972+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-10-04T09:41:36.252978+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-10-04T09:41:36.252981+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-10-04T09:41:36.252983+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-10-04T09:41:36.252985+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-10-04T09:41:36.252987+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-10-04T09:41:36.252989+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-10-04T09:41:36.252992+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-10-04T09:41:36.252994+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-10-04T09:41:36.252996+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-10-04T09:41:36.252998+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253000+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253002+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253004+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253006+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253009+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/learning_log/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253011+00:00 app[web.1]: application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253013+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253016+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253018+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253020+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253022+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253024+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253026+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253029+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253031+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253033+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253036+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253038+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253040+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/learning_log/settings.py", line 141, in <module>
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253042+00:00 app[web.1]: django_heroku.settings(locals())
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253044+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError: name 'django_heroku' is not defined
2019-10-04T09:41:36.253651+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-04 09:41:36 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270886+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-04 09:41:36 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270891+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270893+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270896+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270898+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270900+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270903+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270905+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270908+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270910+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270912+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270914+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270916+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270918+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270920+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270923+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270926+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/learning_log/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270928+00:00 app[web.1]: application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270930+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270932+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270934+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270936+00:00 app[web.1]: configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270938+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270941+00:00 app[web.1]: self._setup(name)
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270969+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270972+00:00 app[web.1]: self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270974+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270976+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270978+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270980+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270982+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/learning_log/settings.py", line 141, in <module>
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270985+00:00 app[web.1]: django_heroku.settings(locals())
2019-10-04T09:41:36.270987+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError: name 'django_heroku' is not defined
2019-10-04T09:41:36.271225+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-04 09:41:36 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2019-10-04T09:41:36.433031+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-04 09:41:36 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2019-10-04T09:41:36.433151+00:00 app[web.1]: [2019-10-04 09:41:36 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2019-10-04T20:08:47.606934+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `rails console` by user rezazandirz@gmail.com
2019-10-04T20:08:52.599170+00:00 heroku[run.8901]: State changed from starting to up
2019-10-04T20:08:52.540958+00:00 heroku[run.8901]: Awaiting client
2019-10-04T20:08:52.558325+00:00 heroku[run.8901]: Starting process with command `rails console`
2019-10-04T20:08:56.882018+00:00 heroku[run.8901]: State changed from up to complete
2019-10-04T20:08:56.861916+00:00 heroku[run.8901]: Process exited with status 127
2019-10-04T20:09:15.082875+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `python console` by user rezazandirz@gmail.com
2019-10-04T20:09:20.315902+00:00 heroku[run.5310]: Awaiting client
2019-10-04T20:09:20.491124+00:00 heroku[run.5310]: State changed from starting to up
2019-10-04T20:09:20.340329+00:00 heroku[run.5310]: Starting process with command `python console`
2019-10-04T20:09:24.747343+00:00 heroku[run.5310]: State changed from up to complete
2019-10-04T20:09:24.740813+00:00 heroku[run.5310]: Process exited with status 2
2019-10-04T20:09:37.338658+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `django console` by user rezazandirz@gmail.com
2019-10-04T20:09:41.769787+00:00 heroku[run.1451]: State changed from starting to up
2019-10-04T20:09:41.628069+00:00 heroku[run.1451]: Awaiting client
2019-10-04T20:09:41.648952+00:00 heroku[run.1451]: Starting process with command `django console`
2019-10-04T20:09:46.022357+00:00 heroku[run.1451]: State changed from up to complete
2019-10-04T20:09:45.998729+00:00 heroku[run.1451]: Process exited with status 127
2019-10-05T17:02:41.040781+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=whispering-peak-53197.herokuapp.com request_id=3e2be804-3022-48a5-b18a-f1e8e25a5373 fwd="104.129.19.20" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: It looks like `django_heroku` isn't installed - maybe run `pip install django-heroku` in a pre-build script?

Comment: No, `django_heroku` isn't *defined* in that file. You didn't import it before you used it. Note, you would have the same error if you ran this locally; why didn't you do that before you deployed?

Comment: I had an 'import Django heroku' in my settings and once I took it out I think everything worked fine. I'm not quite sure if that was it or if something else was it, but I got it working. It was working fine locally with Heroku local, just Heroku open wasn't working. But it works now.